# Altium: Stitching vias applying for multiple nets in multiple channels

Tags: altium, routing

I'm tryint to add stitching vias to my multichannel project.

I have **5 nets** for via stitching to be applied on each channel and **3 channels** in the project. So 15 nets in total.

Looks not too much to make apply stitching manually, however I feel that this is too weird not to have an ability to do it by **net class** or something.

Manually applying stitching will prone to mistakes (I can miss a net or apply stitching to a wrong net by mistake) and time consuming (especially if my project would have more nets and more channels).

Is there any better and more automatic solutions?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Altium doesn't support this. It's multi-channel features look fancy but in practice are inconsistent, buggy and incomplete. I don't know for sure about this specific case though.